# Ruby on Rails - routing error, goes to "show" instead of "index"

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3, ruby-on-rails-3.2

I have a basic homepage with a link that I would like to go to businesses/index.html.erb

```
<%= link_to("Go to businesses index page", {:controller=>"businesses", :action =>"index"}) %>
```

When I click on this link I get a routing error:

```
No route matches {:action=>"show", :controller=>"businesses"}
```

My routes.rb file looks like:

```
RailsProject::Application.routes.draw do
 get "welcome/index"

 root :to => 'welcome#index'

 get "businesses/index"
 resources :businesses
end
```

and `rake routes` gets me:

```
   welcome_index GET    /welcome/index(.:format)       welcome#index
      businesses GET    /businesses(.:format)          businesses#index
                 POST   /businesses(.:format)          businesses#create
    new_business GET    /businesses/new(.:format)      businesses#new
   edit_business GET    /businesses/:id/edit(.:format) businesses#edit
        business GET    /businesses/:id(.:format)      businesses#show
                 PUT    /businesses/:id(.:format)      businesses#update
                 DELETE /businesses/:id(.:format)      businesses#destroy
            root        /                              welcome#index
businesses_index GET    /businesses/index(.:format)    businesses#index
```

I am using rails version 3.2

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem was that in my businesses/index there was a line reading

```
<%= link_to 'show', business_path %>
```

that should have been

```
<%= link_to 'show', business_path(business) %>
```